# Flutter workmanager error Domain=BGTaskSchedulerErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" on iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, background-process, flutter-workmanager

i'm trying to use workermanger with flutter about background service on ios.
So this is my plist

[image]

Now this is my AppDelegate on xcode:

```
 import UIKit
import Flutter
import workmanager


    @UIApplicationMain
    @objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
        
    override func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                            willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
            completionHandler(.alert) // shows banner even if app is in foreground
        }
        
    
        override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
            WorkmanagerPlugin.registerTask(withIdentifier: "simpleTask")
            UIApplication.shared.setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(TimeInterval(60*15))
            GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
            return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
        }
    }
```

and now this is my Flutter code

```
import 'package:workmanager/workmanager.dart';

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
void callbackDispatcher() {
  Workmanager().executeTask((task, inputData) {
    switch (task) {
      case Workmanager.iOSBackgroundTask:
        print("The iOS background fetch was triggered");
        break;
    }
    bool success = true;
    return Future.value(success);
  });
}
void main() {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
   Workmanager().initialize(
    callbackDispatcher, // The top level function, aka callbackDispatcher
    isInDebugMode: true // If enabled it will post a notification whenever the task is running. Handy for debugging tasks
  );
  Workmanager().registerOneOffTask("simpleTask", "simpleTask");
  // Workmanager().registerPeriodicTask("simpleTask", "simpleTask");
  runApp(const MyApp());  
}
```

The error i receive is this:

```
Could not schedule app refresh: Error Domain=BGTaskSchedulerErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)"
```

can you suggest me where i'm lost? Maybe about the documentation, i can't understand i ask help to you.

Comment: [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/bgtaskscheduler/error/code/notpermitted) is the error code 3. Your task identifier `simpleTask` is not in info.plist. See https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/707?time=1435

Comment: @Paulw11 as you can see in the first screenshot, i've added the simpleTask into info.plist

Comment: Ok.  I see that now.  That is why it is better to post code blocks rather than images.  Anyway, code 3 is the error I linked to, which is something wrong with your info.plist.  Are you sure that the right info.plist is ending up in your app bundle?  Archive the app and export the ipa.  Change the extension to .zip and unzip it. Take a look at the info.plist to confirm

Comment: BTW `UIApplication.shared.setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(TimeInterval(60*15))` serves no purpose with background processing tasks

Comment: @Paulw11 i confirm that info.plist have the right parameters about task identifier...can be a bug of the flutter framework on ios 17.2?

Comment: It seems unlikely. I reproduced essentially the same code in a simple Swift app and the only way I get error 3 is if the id didn't match between the code and the plist.  Set a breakpoint in the native code where it submits the request and run your app under Xcode. You can then confirm that the identifier made it from dart to native code correctly.

Comment: @Paulw11 can you share the zip of you project? Just for get me a suggestion and compare my code with you..do you?

Comment: https://github.com/paulw11/BGTask